# How to connect MySQl using php on IBM Bluemix?

Tags: php, mysql, database, ibm-cloud

I am install service MySQL to my PHP app on Bluemix and the error is on connection establish on this lines:

```
$con = mysql_connect("192.155.247.248:3307","uqDqUZ2EKoZ5I","pWXeBZbNtdpOv"); 
if (!$con){ 
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " .mysql_error(); 
} 
mysql_select_db("d65a2b7e14b594d18a049ac918a4a8603",$con);
```

Comment: What is the text of the error?

Comment: @Marcin: is this not a PHP question?

Comment: the app stop on this line$con = mysql_connect("192.155.247.248:3307","uqDqUZ2EKoZ5I","pWXeBZbNtdpOv");

Comment: so the error on connection !! i don't know why !!

Comment: Does it say, "error on connection"? Isn't there a message that is more specific? Is there anything in your MySQL error logs?

Comment: (Sorry Marcin. Not heard back from you to explain your edit, and this is quite plainly a PHP and MySQL question. Rolled back).

Comment: there are other php code after this line and the script stop when it reach to this line

Comment: **Warning**:  You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: is the above syntax is error ? @Quentin

Comment: @ahmed — The `mysql_` functions have been deprecated (and will removed entirely from new versions of PHP)

Comment: What is the error message you get? Are you sure thats the correct port and IP address? Are you sure the DB is accessible over TCP and not just by socket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a folder

.bp-config/options.json in the parent folder

and add

```
{
    "PHP_EXTENSIONS": ["mysqli"]
}
```

in the options.json folder
the sqli connect will work fine now

Answer (score 2):

Quentin suggested to use mysqli instead of mysql_* as the latter is deprecated, i.e. try this:

```
 $mysqli = new mysqli("192.155.247.248:3307","uqDqUZ2EKoZ5I","pWXeBZbNtdpOv", "MYDB");
 $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * from MYTABLE");
 $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: Can you share the new code you're using and what the new error message is?

Comment: @ahmed: if an answer does not help, please try to explain more than "it does not work", since you have not supplied anything new to respond to. If you can explain at length what does not work, and any other new things you have tried, that often helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting:

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '$host' (60).

A developer may have asked a similar question on **[developerWorks](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/8925/how-do-i-connect-to-my-bluemix-mysql-service-to-setup-mysql-database.html)**.

The answer seemed to be as follows:

1. Downloaded the latest PHPMyAdmin(4.1.9)
2. Created a BlueMix application using - `cf push -b https://github.com/dmikusa-pivotal/cf-php-build-pack.git
   ${myPhpAdminApp}` . Note: the PHP build pack is used is PHP 5.4.26, which enables multi-byte support (it is different from the Heroku one in the BlueMix docs). This was necessary because the Heroku pack bundled PHP 5.3.27 which
   doesn't enable "multi-byte" character support by default. Multi-byte
   support is required to be enabled by PHPMyAdmin apparently.
3. Added the existing MySQL service to this app. And picked the host, port, user, and password details from the `VCAP_SERVICES`
   environment variable.
4. Copied `config.sample.inc.php` in the PHPMyAdmin to config.inc.php and added or modified the following lines in it based on the MySQL
   service `VCAP_SERVICES` details picked in previous step -

   ```
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'host-ip-from-vcap_services';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = 'port-from-vcap_services';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'user-from-vcap_services';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'password-from-vcap_services';
   ```
5. Pushed the updates using the above `cf push` ... again.

Comment: I am firstly create the php application on bluemix then add MYSQL service  and then :  $con = mysql_connect("192.155.247.248:3307","uqDqUZ2EKoZ5I","pWXeBZbNtdpOv");   why this not work

Comment: help me please if you know